# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ without using the integral test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This was my first question in this community so I didn't write it carefully. I am improving the question so it might be helpful for others. The answers below take credit for pointing me to the right direction.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. Proof: using the $n^{\text{th}}$ term test, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, hence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. Proof: here we use a lemma from Rudin that states the following

Suppose $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \dots \ge 0$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^k a_{2^k} = a_1 + 2a_2 + 4a_4 + \dots$.

It is clear that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ satisfies the hypothesis, $1 \ge \frac{1}{4} \ge \frac{1}{9} \ge \dots$. Therefore, the series converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^k a_{2^k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \dots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$ converges.

But $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$ is a geometric series and hence $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1 - {\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) ^\infty}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1-0}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2$.

Comment: Show that $a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ is not Cauchy and that $a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: thanks @kingW3, I'm sorry if my question sounds naive but would you mind clarify how to show that 1/n is Cauchy and 1/n^2 is not?

Comment: For 1/n consider $|a_{2n}-a_n|$ it's easy to bound it below by some non zero number (try to figure out which one by yourself) hence it's not Cauchy. For the $\frac1{n^2}$ you can use that $\frac1{n^2}<\frac1{n^2-n}$ and show that $1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n^2-n}$ is convergent.

Comment: For the first series, a common approach is to note that, for every $N\geqslant1$, $$\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n\geqslant\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1{2N}=\frac12$$ For the second series, a common approach is to note that, for every $n\geqslant2$, $$\frac1{n^2}\leqslant\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n$$ Can you conclude in both cases?

Comment: thank you all. It is very clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

observe

$(\frac 13 + \frac 14) \ge \frac 12\\
(\frac 15 + \frac 16 + \cdots +\frac 18) \ge \frac 12\\
(\frac 1{2^k+1} + \frac 1{2^k+2} + \cdots +\frac 1{2^{k+1}}) \ge \frac 12$

$\sum_\limits {n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n} \ge \sum_\limits {k=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{2}$

while

$ (\frac 1{2^2} + \frac {1}{3^2}) \le \frac 12\\ 
(\frac 1{4^2} + \frac 1{5^2}+\frac 1{6^2} + \frac 1{7^2}) \le 4(\frac 1{4})^2 = \frac {1}{2^2}\\
(\frac 1{2^{2k}} + \frac 1{(2^{k}+1)^2} + \cdots +\frac 1{(2^{k+1}-1)^2}) \le 2^k\frac 1{2^{2k}} = \frac {1}{2^k}$

$\sum_\limits {n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n^2} \le \sum_\limits {k=0}^{\infty}\frac {1}{2^k}$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots & > \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots\\
 & = 1+1+1+1+1+\cdots
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\cdots & < \frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots\\
 & = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots=2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

To see that the sum harmonic sum diverges group the terms into groups of size $2^n$ and then bound them below
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} =1+ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=2^i+1}^{2^{j+1}} \frac{1}{j} > 1+ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
and last series clearly diverges.

To show that the harmonic sum of squares converges bound each term below by $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ and use partial fractions to show that this series converges.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} <1+ \sum_{i=2}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{i(i-1)}=1+ \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{i-1}-\frac{1}{i} \right)=2.
\end{eqnarray*}